# EC2 Nginx stuck in SYN_ACK for http requests from single ip

Tags: nginx, networking, amazon-ec2, centos, iptables

I have a single EC2 instance up and running, default amzn2 linux.
I've got HTTP,HTTPS,SSH inbound rules enabled from all ips in the security groups, So it should be accessible from all ip's.

I did

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j LOG
```

and i can see my requests showing up in

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
```

The server is running nginx, that is proxying requests to a node cluster via unix sockets.
All requests seem to go through from other IP addresses except mine. And only HTTP/HTTPS.
So everything seems to work fine, but I can't connect via HTTP/HTTPS from my local development machine, SSH works.

iptables is empty

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've got no clue what might be blocking my requests. And it's driving me insane, I've spend hours figuring it out and got no clue what so ever. Anyone?

**Update**

Seems the TCP connections are stuck in SYN_RECV state. No idea about the root cause.

```
$ netstat -atupen
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 vm.vm.vm.vm:80          my.my.my.my:8857        SYN_RECV    0          0          -
```

vm.vm.vm.vm -> aws internal ip address

my.my.my.my -> my current ip address

Comment: There is additional firewall in AWS, you have to configure it with its own security groups.

Comment: https://ec2-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configure-firewall.html   checkout, and enter your posts, HTTP/HTTPS in your case

Comment: @AbhishekSoni i just described how it's configured. Did you read the question? And I also mentioned the requests do show up in the VM

Answer (score 1):

By any means, is your instance in a VPC with some custom ACLs?

SYN_RECV means that the first SYNC and the SYN/ACK passed the firewalls properly, so you might want to investigate why your client cannot send the last ACK.

Do you have some kind of Firewall on your Computer / router, or connectivity issues with your network?

Kind Regards

Comment: Not that i know of, the issue seems to be on the hardware though, no requests arrive to NGINX? Nothing shows up in the nginx logs.

Comment: Any ideas how i could dig deeper to the root cause?

Comment: ok according to tcpdump the server is sending SYN/ACK packets however they never arrive to my local machine. Wireshark says, my machine is retransmitting SYN packages as curl haven't received the ACK from the server.
I am wondering if it's AWS blocking the outgoing responses, or iptables or some local firewall that i'm unaware of.

Comment: You seem to run your Nginx on CentOS7 maybe you could look at firewalld with **firewall-cmd --list-ports**.
Also, security groups are **stateful**, so if the packet can come in, it will by able to go out, the only **stateless** firewall on AWS is the **VPC ACLs**, which may cause problem if they aren't configured properly. To check this out, go to your VPC and check ACLs.